# Does the cin function add null terminated at the end of input?

Tags: c++, user-input, c-strings

If I declare a character array: `char arr[200]`
and then I subsequently use the function cin to read values into `arr[200]`
and I type into the command window line: abcd

Is there a null terminated: `\0` automatically added to the array at the end of the input?

(I don't think so because I tested it using the cin function: cin>>abcd )

Can somebody explain it to me why?

Below is a snippet of my code I use to test

```
    char arr[200]
    int count=0;
    int i=0;
    cin>>arr // i type into command window:abcd

    while (arr[i] != '\0')
    {
       count++;
        i++




    }
```

My count value will not be 4 but like 43 hence I concluded that the character array is not null terminated after the cin function

Comment: you should have a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/

Comment: i edited the question for better understanding

Comment: Neither i nor count is initialized.

Comment: i tried with initialisation, the result is the same

Comment: The code you've posted (after fixing the syntax errors), with input "abcd", sets `count` to 4 as expected. [Here is a demonstration](http://ideone.com/NAcsa4). Either the code you're running or your input are different to what you've posted, or your library is buggy.

Comment: @ManojR i am a beginner so i have no idea what is turbo

Comment: @MikeSeymour you are correct, but i cant figure out whats wrong with my code can you help me checks thanks http://ideone.com/bgqJnM

Comment: @Lim: You're measuring the length *before* reading into the array. At that point, it contains garbage so you could get any result. The code you've posted here correctly measures the length *after* reading.

Comment: turboc is the compiler. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ManojR MS Visual Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatted input from a `std::istream` into a character array will null-terminate the input, as specified in C++11 27.7.2.2.3/9:

> `operator>>` then stores a null byte (`charT()`) in the next position

The code you've posted gives the expected result once the obvious syntax errors are fixed. But beware that this is very dangerous; there is no check on the length of the array, so too much input will overflow it. I strongly recommend you use the `std::string` class, rather than plain character arrays, for managing strings.

The code you posted in a comment via a [link](http://ideone.com/bgqJnM) looks like this:

```
char array[20];
int length=getlength(array);
cin>>array;
```

reading into the array *after* attempting to measure the string length of the uninitialised array. This could give any result, or crash, or cause any other example of undefined behaviour.

In future, you should make sure that the code you post in your question is the same code that exhibits the behaviour you're asking about; otherwise, it's impossible to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the input will be zero-terminated. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to, for example, print it without printing random characters after your input.

Comment: then why is my count value like 43

Comment: @RayLim It isn't here. Your compiler is broken.

Comment: @Lim [Works fine for me.](http://ideone.com/JVAuNx)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  i guess maybe my complier is broken. Heres a snippet of my code , maybe u can figure it out : http://ideone.com/bgqJnM#

Comment: @Lim Your code provided isn't the same as the one you posted in the question. You are checking `getLength` before you ever put anything into the array so the value is ambiguous and shouldn't be tested before you actually initialize the variable.

Comment: @TheCapn The code is C++, there is no `length` attribute for arrays. Other than that you are correct.

Comment: Whoops. I'll ammend that. Thought I was browsing Java