# Remove Consecutive Duplicates Recursively giving infinite recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, recursion, char

Not a homework question.
I am self learning.
I have to remove consecutive characters in a string by recursion. However the program I made is not working for inputs containing duplicates. It is goining in infinite recursion and hence gives segmentation fault. However it is working for inputs which doesn't have consecutive duplicates in them. I have tried debugging in Eclipse Ide but things get weird when I debug. (I know how to debug) but I can't figure out the things are different when I debug and when I run. I will give you example after my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void removeConsecutiveDuplicates(char *input) {
    int l = strlen(input);
    if(l == 0) {
      return;
    }
    if(input[0] != input[1]) {
        removeConsecutiveDuplicates(input+1);
        return;
    }
    int i = 1;
    for(; input[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
      input[i-1] = input[i];
    }
    input[i] = '\0';
    removeConsecutiveDuplicates(input);
}
int main(void) {
    char ch[1000];
    cin >> ch;
    cout<<"The String Before Removing Duplicates : "<<ch<<endl;
    removeConsecutiveDuplicates(ch);
    cout<<"The String After Removing Duplicates : "<<ch<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I am debugging this code I and seeing the variable l value it is 16. This doesn't happen while running. What I am missing here?

Comment: What is the input of your code? You should really use `std::string` instead of `char ch[1000]` in C++.

Comment: Input : abc
O/p : abc 
Input : aabccde
O/P : abcde

Comment: The recursive call is not really helping your code here. You could just loop around. Recursion should be avoided is possible.  If you are doing it as an exercise then I would replace the for loop with a memmove. The loop looks a bit strange.  Usually the initialisation of i is after the for. I would expect a while here instead. Possibly a do while. Is the writing of the null char required as it is a condition of exiting the loop anyway. Try adding if(input[i] != '\0'), I suspect it is never triggered and can be removed.

Comment: [c++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e069c5c9f759028d): `string text;  cin >> text; cout << "Before : " << text << "\n"; text.erase(std::unique(text.begin(), text.end()), text.end());  cout << "After  : " << text << "\n";`

Comment: In C++, you may do `*std::unique(input, input + strlen(input)) = '\0';`.

Comment: I just wanted to used recursion here for now. And thank for introducing me a new function

Comment: @Jarod42 even better, thanks :)

Comment: I would remove for loop and use memmove(). Not sure if your loop is the issue.

Comment: Issue is resolved. It was just placing null character incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
input[i] = '\0';
```

doesn't do anything (`input[i]` already has that value, because that was the end condition for the loop). You then call the `removeConsecutiveDuplicates` function recursively, but the length of the string is still the same, so you'll keep making recursive calls until a stack overflow happens.

Instead, you need to make the string length smaller :

```
input[i - 1] = '\0';
```

to avoid this infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

To pass your self-assigned homework problem :), explain why the following line never has any effect in your code:

```
input[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: Got it here. this line is just doing nothing change

Answer (score 1):

In your function, change this:

```
input[i] = '\0';
```

to this:

```
input[i-1] = '\0';
```

since you have chopped away a character, thus you should decrease the size of your string.

Without that, you wouldn't reduce the size, thus looping over and over again the same size, without it changing, would result in an infinite loop (since the size wouldn't change).

---

I suggest you use an [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) next time, since this is C++.

Comment: But why this is working here? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-consecutive-duplicates-string/
I have just replaced the definition of function with the above website answer and it is working fine

Comment: You are [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744897/does-cin-function-add-null-terminated-at-the-end-of-input) @SanderDeDycker, sorry.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore I was wrong, sorry, please see my updated answer. +1 for your question.

Comment: You are right in this. I will use string. I think that is the reason I am getting weird 
The String Before Removing Duplicates : 51-thread-select
When I am debugging